# Ar_pose doesn't recognize tag in tum_simulator. Please help

Tags: ros, ar-pose, ardrone-autonomy, tum-simulator, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to use ar_pose with image from ardrone camera. I don't have real quadrotor, I am using tum_simulator with Gazebo.

My problem is that ar_pose doesn't recognize tags in simulation, so I have few questions:

screens:

Gazebo and ar_tag which I add [image description http://snag.gy/vYzFi.jpg](http://snag.gy/vYzFi.jpg)

1. Should I do camera calibration? (I don't have real cam, I am using cam which is in tum_simulator)
2. What parameters should be set in ar_pose like: marker marker_width? (I am using tags in simulation)
3. Why ar_pose doesn't recognize this tag?

**EDIT:
what I have done?**

I have add two lines to launch file which is responsible for running Gazebo + tum_simulator + ardrone_autonomy

```
<remap from="/ardrone/camera_info" to="/camera/camera_info"/>
<remap from="/ardrone/image_raw" to="/camera/image_raw"/>
```

so when I launch this files I have above topics remapped:
http://pastebin.com/vv0UpGRp

next I launch ar_pose:

```
<launch>

  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" 
    args="-d $(find ar_pose)/launch/live_single.rviz"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="world_to_cam" 
    args="0 0 0.5 -1.57 0 -1.57 world camera 10" />

 
  <node name="ar_pose" pkg="ar_pose" type="ar_single" respawn="false"
    output="screen">
    <param name="marker_pattern" type="string"
      value="$(find ar_pose)/data/4x4/4x4_19.patt"/>
    <param name="marker_width" type="double" value="200"/>
    <param name="marker_center_x" type="double" value="0.0"/>
    <param name="marker_center_y" type="double" value="0.0"/>
    <param name="threshold" type="int" value="100"/>
    <param name="use_history" type="bool" value="true"/>
 
  </node>
</launch>
```

RESULTS:
screen from rviz (simulation) [image description http://snag.gy/vLwJj.jpg](http://snag.gy/vLwJj.jpg)

(screen1) [image description http://snag.gy/bdjWd.jpg](http://snag.gy/bdjWd.jpg)

Problem is that there is warming NO IMAGE RECEIVED and it is true. Preview from camera using 'CAMERA' gives black window, preview should be done with 'IMAGE'.
AR_POSE uses this 'camera style' preview, no 'image style'.
How to solve this problem?
(screen2) [image description http://snag.gy/PBK0v.jpg](http://snag.gy/PBK0v.jpg)

**info from marker section:
basic_shapes/1
For frame [ardrone_base_frontcam]: No transform to fixed frame [camera]. TF error: [Could not find a connection between 'camera' and 'ardrone_base_frontcam' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.]**
(screen3) [image description http://snag.gy/zxhrW.jpg](http://snag.gy/zxhrW.jpg)

EDIT:

it started working!
I change fixed frame to ar_marker and it seems to be working! :)

but it gives me message in terminal:

```
[ERROR] [1417704617.003409185, 3461.051000000]: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "ar_marker" from authority "unknown_publisher" because of a nan value in the transform (0.609564 -0.180967 -3.568543) (-nan -nan -nan -nan)
[ERROR] [1417704622.185442670, 3463.722000000]: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "ar_marker" from authority "unknown_publisher" because of a nan value in the transform (0.984986 -0.604149 -2.678788) (nan nan nan nan)
[ERROR] [1417704623.374384366, 3464.377000000]: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "ar_marker" from authority "unknown_publisher" because of a nan value in the transform (0.590453 -0.226787 -2.891703) (nan nan nan nan)
```

(screen4) [image description http://snag.gy/vOyiq.jpg](http://snag.gy/vOyiq.jpg)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198576/ar_pose-doesn%27t-recognize-tag-in-tum_simulator.-please-help./) by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2014-11-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-12-02**:
Cześć, używasz ar_sys czy ar_pose ?

**Comment by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on 2014-12-02**:
Cześć :)
wolałbym pisać po ang ponieważ jest większe prawdop. że ktoś jeszcze może mi pomóc.

I am using ar_pose from this localisation: https://github.com/xqms/ar_tools/tree/catkin
do you have any idea?

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-12-02**:
nie ma sprawy. And i tried to use ar_pose but it was a little difficult to setup and it seems as if maintenance hasnt been done in a while . Not sure what changes where made on the fork you are using though. Have you looked at [ar_sys](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_sys)? Just started to set it up myself

**Comment by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on 2014-12-04**:
I haven't heard about this package before. You are using real camera or camera in gazebo simulator? Everything works fine?

Some time ago I found this repository: http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar

I have calibrated ar_pose to my cam in laptop so I would rather don't change repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you've hit on the problem in #2: there needs to be a white border around the marker in order for it to be detected.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-12-02**:
Agreed. This would cause a issue

**Comment by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on 2014-12-04**:
I have added white borders to this tag, changed way of remapping and changed fixed frame.
It works, I am a little bit surprised. Could you look at the error which I pasted at the bottom of the post?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi green96, I'm trying to do the same as you. Can you tell me how you include a marker in gazebo? Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [pulver](https://answers.ros.org/users/22461/pulver/) with karma: 51 on 2016-04-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1